# Query works in one sheet, but not in another?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

This `QUERY` works on one sheet, but not another.  Both sheets appear to be formatted the exact same with the same data, but when I try to apply it to my working sheet, I get a "`AVG_SUM_ONLY_NUMERIC`" error. I assume it must have something to do with the formatting of the column, but even after changing the formatting to "automatic", it still doesn't work.

Here is the formula in question:

```excel
=QUERY(QUERY(projectMaterials!A3:K, 
 "select A,sum(B),C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K 
  where A is not null 
  group by A,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K", 0),
 "offset 1", 0)
```

It works on [this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1g2pkjc8w9Ty12Lpuwyljx0K-afsja6XShUCKB7YJm98/edit#gid=915715697&range=A2), but not on [this one](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-FdpxsNcrqXXWroYzeAQZz5TuyEX6xKnTif0rrrJl60/edit#gid=1375654420&range=B3)...

Comment: AVG_SUM_ONLY_NUMERIC means that B column is read by query as text not numeric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({projectMaterials!A3:A,projectMaterials!B3:B*1,projectMaterials!C3:K}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2),Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11
  label sum(Col2)''", 0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for fixing the formula.  The only thing is, now it doesn't group together as intended (like it does on the first sheet.)  What do I need to do to get it to actually group together?  By column A, preferably?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1g2pkjc8w9Ty12Lpuwyljx0K-afsja6XShUCKB7YJm98/edit#gid=915715697&range=A2 is private sheet

Comment: also grouping by too many columns will actually not group data if values of those columns are different. in such case query should contain only relevant columns and rest should be processed by vlookup

Comment: Fixed the sharing issue. But I see what you mean about it not grouping because of the different locations in Col4.  I can work with that.  My other question is, what is the purpose of the `projectMaterials!B3:B*1`. Other than that, thank you very much for solving the issue for me, once again!

Comment: as mentioned before, the query does not recognize B column as numeric so we just multiply B column by 1 to force conversion from plain text to numeric. it's same as wrapping B column into VALUE - but shorter